# How to mimic Unix File System in Windows?

Tags: java

File has been created in Unix Box (Server). I am downloading it to my local Windows Box (Client) using RMI. To do testing, I dont have any Unix box currently available, is there any way to mimic Unix File System in java?

Comment: Do you use OS specific classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an unix emulator for windows like cygwin.
Setup guide [here](https://cygwin.com/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install a virtual machine like VirtualBox and install Unix in it.  This will allow you to run a full Unix like an application.

Answer (score 0):

mingw is more simple and thus has small functionalty. But was very usefull when making a  jni environmens.